# Play a specific movie by pressing button inside a detailview reached from tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, mpmovieplayercontroller, detailview

and thanks in advance for your time.

What I need to get is perfectly shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfD9shN8-8U): unfortunetly I can't find anywhere the code of this project from this yound great developer.

I followed a tutorial which owns the In-App Purchase's process, and everything is ok: I retrieve my product IDs, buy, restore..anything is ok.

If I tap a row BEFORE my transaction finishes, I got a detail view containing a "Purchase this before!!" message: the PrepareForSegue send this message for me to the user.

Instead, once my transaction is completed, when I tap the row of the specific product inside my dynamic table view, I reach my dynamic Detail View containing images and labels
making use of IBOutlet connections from "datamodel".

What I'm asking you is, PLEASE...PLEASE... to help me CREATING on this detailView a Button with his IBAction, it has to load the movies related to the Cell I tapped in the previos table view.

The working project I'm talking about is [here](http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/downloads/InAppRagePart2Starter.zip), and hope it is useful to help me.
I didn't change any variable, method, class..nothing.

I think I should create an array of movies owned by a MoviePlayerController, so the button prototyped fires the IBAction "Play THAT SPECIFIC Url".. but after weeks of searches...I'm here on my knees in front of you.

As result of my research, I tried to understand what discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205090/play-movie-audio-and-display-contents-of-a-folder-in-detailview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866310/movie-player-in-new-view-controller-does-not-play-movie-from-dynamic-url-iphone) but with no success.

Hope my english is good enough to be understood. Forgive me, I'm Italian ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it yesterday, yeeeeah ;-)

I've created a generic variable which handles the namefile of the video, passed from the prepareForSegue method using a series of "if / then" statements.